# Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use coolbox_id.set() instead. helpme

Tags: python, django-models, django-views

I am getting this error when i use many to many field help me plsssssss

#### views.py

```
def add_ship(request):
    
    if request.method=='POST':
        
        m_namedriver = request.POST.get('m_namedriver')
        driver_id = Driver.objects.get(driver_id=m_namedriver)

        m_licensepl = request.POST.get('m_licensepl')
        car_id = Car.objects.get(car_id=m_licensepl)

        m_weightcoolbox = request.POST.get('m_weightcoolbox')
        coolbox_id = Coolbox.objects.get(coolbox_id=m_weightcoolbox)

        ship_date = request.POST.get('ship_date')
        ship_time = request.POST.get('ship_time')
        original = request.POST.get('original')
        destination = request.POST.get('destination')

        if shipping.objects.count() != 0:
            ship_id_max = shipping.objects.aggregate(Max('shipping_id'))['ship_id__max']
            next_ship_id = ship_id_max[0:2] + str(int(ship_id_max[2:6])+1)
        else:
            next_ship_id = "SP1000"

        new_shipping = shipping.objects.create(
                shipping_id = next_ship_id,
                driver_id = driver_id,
                car_id = car_id,
                coolbox_id = coolbox_id,
                ship_date = ship_date,
                ship_time = ship_time,
                original = original,
                destination = destination,
            )

        new_shipping.save()
        new_shipping.coolbox_id.add(coolbox_id)

        return render(request,'add_ship.html',{'message1':"Add shipping successful."})
    driver_ship = Driver.objects.all()
    car_ship = Car.objects.all()
    coolbox_ship = Coolbox.objects.all()
    return render(request,'add_ship.html',{'driver_ship':driver_ship,'car_ship':car_ship,'coolbox_ship':coolbox_ship})
```

I've been stuck here for 3 days now. At first I used it as a CharField so I could add it, but when I added another ID it couldn't add it. It says there is a problem in this part   ship_id_max = shipping.objects.aggregate(Max('shipping_id'))['ship_id__max']

#### models.py

```
class Coolbox(models.Model):
    coolbox_id = models.CharField(max_length=40,primary_key=True)
    medicine_name = models.ForeignKey(Medicine, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="medicinename")
    weight = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    coolboxtemp_max = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    coolboxtemp_min = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    dimension = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    d_measurement = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    t_measurement = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    total = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.medicine_name}"




class shipping(models.Model):
    shipping_id = models.CharField(max_length=15,primary_key=True)
    driver_id = models.ForeignKey(Driver, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="driverfk")
    
    car_id = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="carfk")
    coolbox_id = models.ManyToManyField(Coolbox,  related_name="coolboxfk")
    ship_date = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    ship_time = models.TimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    original = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.shipping_id}: {self.driver_id}"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ETy3.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEFzZ.png)

#### HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                        <div class="form-outline multip_select_box">
                          <label class="form-label" for="Coolboxs">Coolboxs ID</label>
                          <br>
                          <select name="m_weightcoolbox" id="m_weightcoolbox" class="multi_select form-control"  multiple data-selected-text-format="count > 3" >
                            {% for m_weightcoolbox in coolbox_ship %}
                            
                            <option value="{{ m_weightcoolbox.coolbox_id }}">{{ m_weightcoolbox.coolbox_id }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                            
                          </select>
                          
                          

                                                        
                          
                        </div>
      
                      </div>
                    </div>  



enter code here
```

Help me plsssssssssss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a List of objects of not a single object at save

you can do like this ...

```
def add_ship(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        
        m_namedriver = request.POST.get('m_namedriver')
        driver_id = Driver.objects.get(driver_id=m_namedriver)

        m_licensepl = request.POST.get('m_licensepl')
        car_id = Car.objects.get(car_id=m_licensepl)

        m_weightcoolbox = request.POST.getlist('m_weightcoolbox')
        print(m_weightcoolbox)
        coolb_id = [i for i in Coolbox.objects.filter(coolbox_id__in=m_weightcoolbox)]
        ship_date = request.POST.get('ship_date')
        ship_time = request.POST.get('ship_time')
        original = request.POST.get('original')
        destination = request.POST.get('destination')

        if shipping.objects.count() != 0:
            ship_id_max = shipping.objects.aggregate(Max('shipping_id'))["shipping_id__max"]
            next_ship_id = ship_id_max[0:2] + str(int(ship_id_max[2:6])+1)
        else:
            next_ship_id = "SP1000"

        new_shipping = shipping.objects.create(
                shipping_id = next_ship_id,
                driver_id = driver_id,
                car_id = car_id,
                ship_date = ship_date,
                ship_time = ship_time,
                original = original,
                destination = destination,
            )
        new_shipping.coolbox_id.set(coolb_id)
        return redirect("add_ship")

        return render(request,'add_ship.html',{'message1':"Add shipping successful."})
    driver_ship = Driver.objects.all()
    car_ship = Car.objects.all()
    coolbox_ship = Coolbox.objects.all()
    return render(request,'add_ship.html',{'driver_ship':driver_ship,'car_ship':car_ship,'coolbox_ship':coolbox_ship})
```

## CODE

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18v_BgTLSmMLhfNCDojhYlTeqkfUsASqt/view?usp=share_link

## OUTPUT

after downloading Animatoin.gif file open it in Chrome Browser it's the full video of working with your project

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1klxwCUb47UI2NimCnSvrqkpc2SB0691S/view?usp=share_link

Comment: thx but not working or did I do something wrong? I'm new to django

Comment: Are you working with Django HTML or Rest framework ???

Comment: Answer is updated please check it

Comment: it not working It adds but the coolbox_id doesn't come with it. I checked in the database.

Comment: plz send me repo link

Comment: Please put html form screenshot

Comment: gh repo clone Saiya9/coolchain

Comment: https://github.com/Saiya9/coolchain

Comment: Repo open 404 page not found

Comment: https://github.com/Saiya9/coolchain.git

Comment: Here fixed your problem plz download your repo from this link

here....

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18v_BgTLSmMLhfNCDojhYlTeqkfUsASqt/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Answer is also updated

Comment: i am so very thankful for your time. i am so grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_ship(request):

if request.method=='POST':
    
    m_namedriver = request.POST.get('m_namedriver')
    driver_id = Driver.objects.get(driver_id=m_namedriver)

            m_licensepl = request.POST.get('m_licensepl')
    car_id = Car.objects.get(car_id=m_licensepl)

    m_weightcoolbox = request.POST.get('m_weightcoolbox')
    coolbox_id = Coolbox.objects.get(coolbox_id=m_weightcoolbox)

    ship_date = request.POST.get('ship_date')
    ship_time = request.POST.get('ship_time')
    original = request.POST.get('original')
    destination = request.POST.get('destination')

    if shipping.objects.count() != 0:
        ship_id_max = shipping.objects.aggregate(Max('shipping_id'))['ship_id__max']
        next_ship_id = ship_id_max[0:2] + str(int(ship_id_max[2:6])+1)
    else:
        next_ship_id = "SP1000"

    new_shipping = shipping.objects.create(
            shipping_id = next_ship_id,
            driver_id = driver_id,
            car_id = car_id,
            coolbox_id = coolbox_id,
            ship_date = ship_date,
            ship_time = ship_time,
            original = original,
            destination = destination,
        )

    new_shipping.save()
    new_shipping.shipping.add(coolbox_id)

    return render(request,'add_ship.html',{'message1':"Add shipping successful."})
driver_ship = Driver.objects.all()
car_ship = Car.objects.all()
coolbox_ship = Coolbox.objects.all()
return render(request,'add_ship.html',{'driver_ship':driver_ship,'car_ship':car_ship,'coolbox_ship':coolbox_ship})
```

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer, or an edit to the question? Please don't use the answer section for further clarifications to your question, reserve it for answers only.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                        <div class="form-outline multip_select_box">
                          <label class="form-label" for="Coolboxs">Coolboxs ID</label>
                          <br>
                          <select name="m_weightcoolbox" id="m_weightcoolbox" class="multi_select form-control"  multiple data-selected-text-format="count > 3" >
                            {% for m_weightcoolbox in coolbox_ship %}
                            
                            <option value="{{ m_weightcoolbox.coolbox_id }}">{{ m_weightcoolbox.coolbox_id }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                            
                          </select>
                          
                          

                                                        
                          
                        </div>
      
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: @Mahammadhusain kadiwala Django html

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer, or an edit to the question? Please don't use the answer section for further clarifications to your question, reserve it for answers only.